# image served from another site won't open popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, textblock, access-denied

I think I know the answer already is probably "No", but I'll ask anyway, (as there may be a work around like a "lightbox" option etc)

I wrote a banner exchange script, with a difference. When the banner is clicked, a new window opens appears inviting the user to subscribe to a newsletter first, (or go straight to site)

This works fine if I use a window.open() prompt, as effectively the text for the popup is pulled in from URL of the window ... but I want to use a (modal?) window without the location bar etc. But here's the problem: The script runs on siteA, and displays the banners on HTML page of siteB. When you click the banner, it cannot access the javascript/CSS modal window code on the host HTML page. I think even with a light box div, the image or link has to be "hard coded" into the HTML page first. Can anyone envisage a work-around?

Here is what I've tried thus far (in simplified form):

```
<script>
hide id 0
</script>

<div>
<object data=pop-up text pulled from Site A: visibility:hidden id=0 width="720" height="600">
</div>
<object data=banner code pulled from SiteA width="490" height="90">
```

(I tried running the javascript from site A, and calling the hide routine via parent.document... to get to the javascript hide routine within the HTML page. Adding an alert to this 'calling' javascript, I get "SiteA says: hallo" when I click the banner)

I also tried jumping the banner to a script that would redraw the code to "_top" of the browser, and display the pop-up code in a div on this new page. I tried window.history.back to get the HTML from the page we've just left ... but all that does is reload the same page and discard the new  code

I made the second object code above 'almost' same size as banner so text above and below if on HTML page flows properly.

- On a slight tangent, it there a way to print a "block" of code in Javasript. In PERL, you can use "print <<EOF", but at present, if I want to print a large amount of text via javascript, I'm using +'xxxx xxx xxx xx' +'xxx xxx xxx' and escaping each and every single quote and newline. Is there a better way to print a line of code that contains numerous newline feeds?

Comment: Perhaps clean up this question a bit, it's a bit hard to follow, and the sample doesn't look valid, there's no quotes around the "".  I'm not being facetious, I just want you to get an answer.

Comment: The code above isn't meant to be a working example, it was merely to illustrate the three "sections" I'm using, ie 1) a javascript routine to show the popup using a "visibility:visible" code, 2) an object which contains the popup table data, (currently hidden) and the 3) code that brings in graphic from Site A. The principle is, when the graphic is clicked, it runs the javascript routine which then makes section 2 visible on screen. However, because the image data is being loaded from one site, and the HTML is on a second, the former is denied access.

Comment: (out of room above) I should also add that it's not just a simple graphic; it is within an <A> tag so that when the graphic is clicked, the javascript opens the popup, then jumps to external script to add credits to the user account so their their banner is displayed on other sites. What i'm investigating today is preloading images into javascript so that the image will be part of the HTML code of site displaying banners.

Comment: Hi @Cristofayre,the example seems to be missing closing quotes even. I just feel it's hard to understand what you are saying, I think the language or wording used isn't easy to follow, but it might make sense to someone else!  Somethings that don't make sense (might be useful when speaking to other devs): "using a "visibility:visible" code" (you mean style?), "code that brings in graphic from Site A"(what does 'brings in' mean?), "is denied access" (what is denying?).  Lastly, can't you create a jsfiddle online example of something that isn't working so we can look at the actual code piece?